# As3 optimizing bitmap data method

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmapdata

I am trying to optimize the following method

```
public function update() : void   {
    if (_player.playing && !_player.paused) {
        bitmapData.lock();
        bitmapData.fillRect(_clippingRect, 0);
        bitmapData.draw(_player.container, null, null, null, _clippingRect);
        bitmapData.unlock();
        invalidateContent();
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me if perhaps using copypixels or some other method might optimize the update function?

Comment: Hi, if _clippingRect at the fillrect and draw are superposing then you do not need to fillrect with black I think(kind of optimization). Just my two cents.

Comment: I think there can be no optimization in here, perhaps maybe except `invalidateContent()` unless it's your method which does something valuable.

Answer (score 1):

Use copyPixels() method instead of draw(). These links should help you

[Composing BitmapData Scenes](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1417)

[Display list vs. blitting - the results!](http://blog.iainlobb.com/2010/11/display-list-vs-blitting-results.html)

Comment: If there's no bitmapData under that `_player.container` of his, this is no solution. While yes, pre-rendering anything graphical into bitmaps can go a long way towards optimization.